# How to reduce gap between items in a flex

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

I'm trying to reduce the gap in between my images that expand when hovered over.

I want it to look like this:
[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK7KR.jpg)

But it currently looks like this: [reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7zNb.jpg)

What I currently have:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 15%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mask {
  flex: 1;
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 60% 0, 30% 100%, 10% 100%);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  gap: 2px;
}

.mask>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.mask:hover {
  flex: 1 2 5%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/4434/3729">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/15/2500/1667">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/5000/3333">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried playing around with margins, using negative values even, but that doesn't seem to be right.

Appreciate any advice, thank you.

Comment: `gap` doesn't do anything on your `mask` divs, that's for flex containers. I'm not a CSS expert so I hope someone will have a better solution, but I believe you'll need to reduce the width on your `img`s (and adjust your mask `clip-path` to compensate) in the non-hover state, and revert to a 100% `width` on hover.

Comment: Will the images always be four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clip-path` won't make elements become smaller, they are still here but invisible. So the gap you want to reduce is the actual width of elements.

I have two solutions but both not perfect.

1. Use `clip-path` and change width of `.mask` by `flex-basis` and `flex-grow`.

```css
.container {
  --gap: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 15%;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.mask {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
  flex-basis: calc(calc(100% - 3 * var(--gap)) / 4 * 0.6);
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 100% 0, 60% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.mask>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.mask:hover {
  flex-grow: 1;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/4434/3729">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/15/2500/1667">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/5000/3333">
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Use `skewX` and avoid `.mask` overlap by `margin`. If `.container`'s height will change. You may need js to calculate perfect margin.

```css
.container {
  --gap: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 15%;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.mask {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
  flex-basis: 50px;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
}

.mask>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.mask:hover {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 40px;
  transform: skewX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/4434/3729">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/15/2500/1667">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667">
  </div>
  <div class="mask">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/5000/3333">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Shuo option 2 works perfectly actually. Not sure if it is allowed to ask another question in here, but I tried putting an <a> tag to the <img> tag as per normal but that ends up breaking the styling. Still new to all of this so i'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: That's because the image's selector (`.mask>img`) will not working if you wrap <img> by elements without `.mask`. You can change to `.mask>a>img` or `.mask img`.